# 1155URIStorage not available in npm package but is available on OpenZeppelin Github

Tags: solidity, hardhat, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, erc-1155

I can import
`import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155URIStorage.sol";`  on **Remix**.

But it throws an **error** in **Hardhat**.

I have attached a picture of node_modules and it doesn't seem to include ERC1155URIStorage.

[image]

Is this the package issue or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version are you using? Coz I can see this file on my computer, I have version 4.8.0.
[image]

Comment: The OZ contracts upgradeable folder which already has the normal contracts folder doesn't have it. 

"@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable": "^4.9.2"